# error in checkout page using PHP

Tags: php, insert

I creating a site for online shopping cart using PHP. I did everything but my question is when i checkout the items, only one item will stored in database. But i need to store all selected items records

This is my checkout.php code

```
<?php
//Pay success insert into databace 

if(isset($_POST['pay_success']))
{
    $all = array('product_name'=>$p_code, 'product_name'=>$p_name, 'total_amount'=>$amount);
    $columns = implode(",",array_keys($all));
    $escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($all));
    $values  = implode(",", $escaped_values);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO pay_success ('$columns') VALUES ('$values')";
    if($sql==true)
    {
        echo "Success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error".mysql_error();
    }
}

?>
```

Note: This is only insert code and this code echo success but data's not insert

Comment: Then you should iterate with `foreach` or `for`  which contains insert query inside the loop.

Comment: Your `$escaped_values ` contains like `1,2,3` ?

Comment: Thank you for replaying me @SulthanAllaudeen Actually this code is echo success but not stored in database

Comment: Welcome, may i know what value you have in `$all`  can you `print_r` or `echo` it ?

Comment: $all = product_code , product_name, total_amount those are product details fetching from data base

Comment: `$result=mysql_query($sql);` Just put this line after ` $sql = "INSERT INTO pay_success ('$columns') VALUES ('$values')";`

Comment: thank you @  Sulthan Allaudeen it showing error like    "error-You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near"

Comment: Yes, pls show the full error

Comment: error -You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''product_name,total_amount') VALUES ('Television DXT,701.35')' at line 1

Comment: Oh... why `product_name` twice ?

Comment: I guess `array('product_code'=>$p_code, 'product_name'=>$p_name, 'total_amount'=>$amount);`

Comment: now showing same error

Comment: thank you @ Sulthan Allaudeen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are constructing only the Query and not executing the Query

So, You should have

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO pay_success ('$columns') VALUES ('$values')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if($result)
{
    echo "Success";
}
else
{
    echo "error".mysql_error();
}
```

But i strongly recommend you to use mysqli or pdo as mysql is [depreciated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php)

Update :

I guess you should constructed the $all

`$all = array('product_code'=>$p_code, 'product_name'=>$p_name, 'total_amount'=>$amount);`

Comment: error - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''product_code,product_name,total_amount') VALUES ('PD1002,Television DXT,701.35'' at line 1

Comment: Do you have `produce_code` ,`product_name` , `total_amount` coloumns in your table ?

Comment: Can you please do `echo $sql` and show me the output ?

Comment: sorry for delay@ Sulthan Allaudeen this echo INSERT INTO pay_success ('product_code,product_name,total_amount') VALUES ('PD1002,Television DXT,701.35')

Comment: Can you pls check whether it works for you `$sql = "INSERT INTO pay_success ('product_code','product_name','total_amount') VALUES ($p_code,$p_name,$amount)";` ?

Comment: error -You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''product_code','product_name','total_amount') VALUES ('PD1002', 'Television DXT'' at line 1

Comment: ya ok can i send full document to your mail id

Comment: please check the mail

Answer (score 1):

```
 $all = array('product_name'=>$p_code, 'product_name'=>$p_name, 'total_amount'=>$amount);
```

You should not use 'product_name' twice.

Answer (score -1):

after

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO pay_success ('$columns') VALUES ('$values')";
```

line where is the sql excution function

> mysql_query

Comment: errorYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''product_name,total_amount') VALUES ('Television DXT,701.35')' at line 1

Comment: you have to put a single quotes for each parameter passing

Comment: see this line ('Television DXT,701.35') should be
**('Television DXT' , '701.35')**